# Tagging non-modified class arguments in method

Tags: c#

Let's imagine I have class A and B and a function:

```
void func(A a, B b)
{
  a.field = b.field;
}
```

This function modifies a, but not b.

In there anything I can do with in/ref/out argument parameters to signify in the function signature that:

- b is never modified
- a is modified

Or are there C# attributes I can use in order to flag the arguments?

Comment: Neither `a` or `b` are really modified. It just assigns a property of `a`, but `a` in itself is unchanged. At most, you can use read only properties to signal this intent, or find an apropriate name for the method.

Comment: No, there's nothing like `C++`'s `const`. Don't try to bring a mindset from one programming language and apply it in another. In .NET, you'd tend to work via immutable *types* rather than individual instances.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there could still be a way to add attributes for instance to tag the parameters. This way at least this could provide some kind of doc (non-enforced by the compiler)